# gradle not found in jenkins pipeline but in jenkins machine when gradle -v it shows the output of the version

Tags: gradle, jenkins, groovy, pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

```
pipeline {
    
    agent any
    
    stages{
        
        stage('check  gradle'){
            
            steps{
                
                script{
                    
                    sh "gradle -v"
                    
                }    
            
            }
            
        }
        
    }
        
}
```

the error am getting

- gradle -v

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hello@tmp/durable-8dc7916d/script.sh: 1: gradle: not found

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE

can anyone help me out `

Comment: Is the directory with the gradle executable in the `PATH` for the Jenkins process?
Inside your script, try to run `echo $PATH`, then outside of Jenkins try to run `which gradle`